# Thunderbird occasionally does not display notifications on new mail arrival.

Tags: thunderbird, notification, notification-area

Hi Im using Ubuntu 11.

I am using thunderbird as my email client.

When I have a new email received, ubuntu gives me  email notification which appears on my screen.

But sometimes, there is no email notification even though I receive an email. This caused me delay in reading fresh emails.

What may be the reason for this? Is this a bug in Ubuntu? Whats an appropriate solution?

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using this with a priority inbox gmail account by any chance?

Comment: Hi Tenor, i dont know whats a priority box. Thunderbird is just installed normally in my Ubuntu.

Comment: Is the email account using gmail?

Comment: Hi Tenor, yes it is using gmail account

Comment: @Nirmik Thanks for your edit, but its better if introductions like hi, and signatures and lines like thanks,etc are stripped away too. And in no way i am suggesting you to edit just for those. Take care of them only when you are editing something else, for now. (lets not load reviewers too much).(idk where to put it.)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following extension?

https://addons.mozilla.org/it/thunderbird/addon/gnome-integration/?src=search